# Where/how to manually dispose observer of WKWebView estimatedProgress

Tags: ios, xamarin, dispose, key-value-observing, wkwebview

I have been trying to track the estimated loading progress on a WKWebView using KVO on the "estimatedProgress" property in a Xamarin ios UIViewController.

I add an observer like this:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();
    ...
    WkView.AddObserver("estimatedProgress", NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, ProgressObserver);
    ...
}
```

ProgressObserver looks like this:

```
public void ProgressObserver(NSObservedChange nsObservedChange)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Progress {0}", WkView.EstimatedProgress);
}
```

When I run this it returns something like this:

```
2015-11-17 09:29:15.345 testappiOS[10056:1381155] Progress 0.1
2015-11-17 09:29:15.636 testappiOS[10056:1381155] Progress 0.285892975242258
2015-11-17 09:29:15.949 testappiOS[10056:1381169] Warning: observer object was not disposed manually with Dispose()
```

Googling " [Warning: observer object was not disposed manually with Dispose()](https://www.google.no/search?q=Warning%3A+observer+object+was+not+disposed+manually+with+Dispose()&oq=Warning%3A+observer+object+was+not+disposed+manually+with+Dispose()&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58j69i59.1017j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=xamarin+kvo+Warning:+observer+object+was+not+disposed+manually+with+Dispose())" returns information about the need to manually dispose the observer, obviously. But I have not been able to figure out how to apply this to my problem.

Can anyone offer some insight on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you will need to create a private variable to hold the disposable observer:

```
private IDisposable progressObserver;
```

Then assign it from the AddObserver return value but place this to **ViewWillAppear** method instead:

```
this.progressObserver = webView.AddObserver(
    "estimatedProgress", 
    NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, 
    ProgressObserver);
```

Dispose it in **ViewWillDisappear**:

```
this.progressObserver.Dispose();
```